# Is it possible to publish an erratum in another journal?

Tags: publications, journals, errors-erratum

If an author published a paper that contains errors and decides to publish an erratum, but the journal where the article was published is inactive (but its website still exists). Could the author publish the erratum in another journal?

If so, what could the author do to make the article indicate the existence of the erratum?

Comment: Might be field dependent. In math, I'd post to the arXiv and to my personal university website. Is the arXiv, or something similar to it, widely used in your discipline?

Comment: Yes, arxiv is used in my discipline (Economics). And, I had thought about it, but my question is whether it is enough to publish the errata, or if it is necessary to add a notice in the original article (in the journal's website).

Comment: Here is an example. https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-02/S0002-9939-02-06558-9/

Answer (score 2):

What can be published in a journal is up to the editors. If the original was sufficiently important and the errors less than obvious to readers, then an editor might consider it. But they would rather, I surmise, publish a full paper with correct results, citing the old, than just an errata. If you can't make the new work seem significant, I doubt that editors would be interested.

But the editor decides, perhaps with advice from reviewers. You can possibly make a proposal to an editor before spending wasted effort.

Comment: Of course, it is important to find a place for the errata in this case. But my main doubt is whether or not it is necessary to include a notice in the original article, in the journal's website.

Comment: I thought you indicated it was impossible: inactive journal. But that, too, requires action from an editor.

Comment: Note that I as a reader much prefer an errata over a full paper with correct results because it is much clearer in an errata what is going on

Comment: @user111388, I agree, but the editor of a different journal has their own standards about what to publish. It is they who must be convinced. The original journal is a better venue for an erratum.

Comment: @Buffy: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. And yes, the best place to publish the errata would be the original journal. But, since it is impossible, according to what you tell me... it is possible to publish the errata in another journal. Doesn't it matter if there is no notice in the original journal?

Comment: Only the editor can give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of published works contain errors, most don't matter. You need to consider: Whether your errors matter. Supposing they do, is a erratum necessary, or would updating a technical report suffice. Supposing necessity, is the erratum significant. If it is, then you can publish in another journal. Otherwise (journals aren't likely to accept), you could perhaps rewrite the original work to add significance and publish as a revision.

Regarding, the original work pointing towards any new work, you could ask the original publisher, beyond that not much.